# Flicker effect in styles on first load in GatsbyJS

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

When loading the GatsbyJS application, on the first load, the styles are not being applied. They are loading with the delay.

This isn't happening in development but in production build. Please watch the following video .

[image]

`imageStyle`

```
img{
  width: 100px
}
```

`gatsby-browser.js`

```
// custom typefaces
import "typeface-montserrat"
import "typeface-merriweather"
// normalize CSS across browsers
import "./src/normalize.css"
// custom CSS styles
import "./src/style.css"

// Highlighting for code blocks
import "prismjs/themes/prism.css"

import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css"

import "../common/components/Accordion.css"
```

`gatsby-ssr.js`

```
// custom CSS styles
import './src/style.css';

export const onPreRenderHTML = ({
  getHeadComponents,
  replaceHeadComponents,
}) => {
  const headComponents = getHeadComponents();
  const order = [
    'title',
    'base',
    'meta',
    'style',
    'link',
    'noscript',
    'script',
  ];

  const sortedHeadComponents = headComponents
    .slice(0)
    .flat()
    .sort((x, y) => {
      return order.indexOf(x.type) - order.indexOf(y.type);
    });

  replaceHeadComponents(sortedHeadComponents);
};
```

Comment: What kind of styling are you using? Can you provide the `gatsby-browser.js` too?

Comment: I have updated the info, please check it!

Answer (score 0):

Try moving all the bunch of styles and typographies that you have in both (`gatsby-browser.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js`) in the `Layout` component as the [docs suggests](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/creating-global-styles/):

> The best way to add global styles is with a [shared layout component](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/tutorial/part-3/#your-first-layout-component).
> This layout component is used for things that are shared throughout
> the site, including styles, header components, and other common items.

Comment: Tried out, did not work!

Comment: Just to be clear: by "moving" I meant removing all the imports from the `gatsby-browser.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js` and putting them in the `Layout`, not duplicating them in both sides. In that case, I'd suggest commenting/uncommenting one by one to detect which one is the offending module (if any)